# React Native onPress function not working

Tags: react-native

I was puzzled by this react native built-in function, as it does not work or show any other error in debug console

```
  import { Button } from './Components/common;

  renderContent() {
   switch (this.state.loggedIn) {
   case true:
    return (
      <Button onPress={() => console.log('out')}>
        Log Out
      </Button>
    );
   case false:
    return <LoginForm />;
   default:
    return <Spinner size="large" />;
 }
}
```

By changing the code a little bit, I know it is being called

```
   <Button onPress={console.log('out')}>
```

Logs 'out' everytime I tap RR(reload the android simulator)

But why it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you importing the `<Button />` from exactly? Looks like the `<Button />` you are importing is a custom component. AFAIK, `onPress` works on a `<Button />` if you import it from `react-native` Eg,

```
import { Button } from 'react-native'
```

If your `<Button />` is not from RN, how about trying with `onClick` instead?

```
<Button onClick={ ... }>
```

Comment: yes its a custom component, tried your suggestion, does not work either

Comment: Can you paste your code for '. /Comoonents/common' file?